# How to build multiple applications with angular-cli?

Tags: angular-cli

The property `apps` in the `angular-cli.json` file is of array type. If I add a second element into this array, how can I instruct `ng build` to build both elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently `v1.0.0` you can only select app which you want to build by the following command:

`ng build -a appName`

or

`ng build --app appName`

you also will need to add `name` property to each element in the `apps` array so you will have something like that:

`"apps": [
  {
    "name": "app1",
    "root": "src/app1root",
    ...
    },
    {
    "name": "app2",
    "root": "src/app2root",
    ...
    },
    ...
]`

also you can use app indices like `ng build -a 0` or `ng build -a 1` in that case you don't need to specify app names.

From angular-cli [sorces](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/utilities/app-utils.ts) you can see that there is no possibility to run all apps in one command, you should either specify index either app name otherwise `apps[0]` will be used, so you can't build all apps at the same time using one `ng build` call.

Answer (score 8):

Use your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
   "build-projects": "ng build project1 && ng build project2",
}
```

Then run: `npm run build projects`.

Answer (score 5):

I searched the `angular-cli` source code but could not find any reference to code that iterates or otherwise inspects the contents of `apps` as an array.

As of now (`angular-cli` version 1.0.0-beta.15), every instance of code that deals with `apps` uses the first element of the array hardcoded (`apps[0]`). There does not seem to be a way to select an app to build or alter the default behaviour of using the first element of the array.

The JSON schema for the `apps` element describes it this way:

*Properties of the different applications in this project.*

```
/**
 * Properties of the different applications in this project.
 */
apps?: {
    root?: string;
    outDir?: string;
    assets?: string;
    index?: string;
    main?: string;
    test?: string;
    tsconfig?: string;
    prefix?: string;
    mobile?: boolean;
    /**
     * Global styles to be included in the build.
     */
    styles?: string[];
    /**
     * Global scripts to be included in the build.
     */
    scripts?: string[];
    /**
     * Name and corresponding file for environment config.
     */
    environments?: {
        [name: string]: any;
    };
}[];
```

It seems to be a future intent of the project to support building multiple apps out of the same code base but it does not look like it is something doable right now (1.0.0-beta.15 version).

Comment: Ok, I will leave the question open hoping the angular-cli developers implement it in the near future.

Comment: I find angular-cli's lack of documentation disturbing

Comment: @Kamaruni I think so too. My hope is that they will make it better over time, especially now that Angular 2 final is out. There's at least the Github page: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli And don't forget the Wiki: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki

Comment: @Readren please accept an answer and to get angular-cli team attention, you should open an issue/enhancement with them in github :)

Answer (score 4):

As of October 28th, 2019 the proper way [from the docs](https://angular.io/cli/build) to build a specific project:

```
ng build <app name>
```

There is an [open issue in GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11002) to add an ability to build multiple projects at once.

Answer (score 3):

Still there isn't any flag for `ng build --app` to build all apps with one command, so best way to solve this is to create **Makefile** file in root of project:

```
my-app
  --dist/
  --e2e/
  --src/
  .angular-cli.json
  package.json
  Makefile
```

Makefiles allows to organize code compilation according of instructions you provided.
So we need to provide instruction to build frontend for all apps into an output directory.
Now Makefile file looks like this:

```
help:
    @echo "_______BUILD ANGULAR FRONTEND______\n"
    @echo "To build all apps run make make build-frontend"

build-frontend:
    ng build -a=0 &&\
    ng build -a=1
```

However after you copy-paste code above, change spaces into tab. Otherwise you will get invalid Makefile  with `*** missing separator error`

Navigate to root project and just to test, type `make` in terminal and you should get help message printed. After that type:

```
make build-frontend
```

Now you have multiple apps build with just one command.

Comment: Cmdline does not recognize make command. Do I need to install some cli tool to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I also answered a similar question here -> [Angular 6 CLI -> how to make ng build build project + libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181181/angular-6-cli-how-to-make-ng-build-build-project-libraries/51384460#51384460)

This is for >= ng6. If you'd like something for older versions of the cli, you can take a look at this version -> https://gist.github.com/bmarti44/f6b8d3d7b331cd79305ca8f45eb8997b/03c3b788551cd43db38d2f48e207a730aaba5b6f

I created a script that, when placed in the same folder as `angular.json`, will pull in the file, loop over the projects, and build them in batches asynchronously.

Here's a quick gist, you can toggle the output path and the number of asynchronous builds. I've excluded e2e for the moment, but you can remove the reference to the `filteredProjects` function, and it will run for e2e as projects as well. It would also be easy to add this to `package.json` as an npm run script. So far, it has been working well.

https://gist.github.com/bmarti44/f6b8d3d7b331cd79305ca8f45eb8997b

```
const fs = require('fs'),
  spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
  // Custom output path.
  outputPath = '/nba-angular',
  // Number of projects to build asynchronously.
  batch = 3;

let ngCli;

function buildProject(project) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let child = spawn('ng', ['build', '--project', project, '--prod', '--extract-licenses', '--build-optimizer', `--output-path=${outputPath}/dist/` + project]);

    child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(data.toString());
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      process.stdout.write('.');
    });

    child.on('close', (code) => {
      if (code === 0) {
        resolve(code);
      } else {
        reject(code);
      }
    });
  })
}

function filterProjects(projects) {
  return Object.keys(projects).filter(project => project.indexOf('e2e') === -1);
}

function batchProjects(projects) {
  let currentBatch = 0,
    i,
    batches = {};

  for (i = 0; i < projects.length; i += 1) {
    if ((i) % batch === 0) {
      currentBatch += 1;
    }
    if (typeof (batches['batch' + currentBatch]) === 'undefined') {
      batches['batch' + currentBatch] = [];
    }

    batches['batch' + currentBatch].push(projects[i]);
  }
  return batches;
}

fs.readFile('angular.json', 'utf8', async (err, data) => {
  let batches = {},
    batchesArray = [],
    i;

  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  ngCli = JSON.parse(data);

  batches = batchProjects(filterProjects(ngCli.projects));
  batchesArray = Object.keys(batches);

  for (i = 0; i < batchesArray.length; i += 1) {
    let promises = [];

    batches[batchesArray[i]].forEach((project) => {
      promises.push(buildProject(project));
    });

    console.log('Building projects ' + batches[batchesArray[i]].join(','));

    await Promise.all(promises).then(statusCode => {
      console.log('Projects ' + batches[batchesArray[i]].join(',') + ' built successfully!');
      if (i + 1 === batchesArray.length) {
        process.exit(0);
      }
    }, (reject) => {
      console.log(reject);
      process.exit(1);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 6+:

```
**Dev build**

ng build --project="second-app"

**Prod build**

ng build --configuration production --project="second-app"
```